# Is there a PHP function that does the opposite of mysqli::real_escape_string?

Tags: php, escaping

I'm part of a team, using `json_encode()` to change an array into a JSON string. I then save this string in my database. Our ORM then escapes the quotes in the string, so if I look in the database, the string is stored as something like this:

```
"{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Number five\",\"color":\"red"}"
```

I can obviously write a method to remove the escaping, but I wanted to check first: Is there an existing, built-in function for unescaping?

====

EDIT: The value is stored this way in the database. Even looking via the command-line mysql command shows this. And when it is re-fetched in my application, it also shows up with the slashes.

Comment: *"if I look in the database"* - How specifically are you observing this?  Is the data actually stored like this, or is the tool that's viewing the data doing this?  In your application, when you re-fetch the data from the database, is it valid JSON?

Comment: @David good question. The value is stored this way in the database. Even looking via the command-line `mysql` command shows this. And when it is re-fetched, it also shows up with the slashes.

Comment: _"the string is stored as something like this"_ - _including_ those outer, _not_ escaped double quotes?

Comment: If your ORM does "additional" escaping on the way in, then it should reverse that again, on the way out. If it doesn't do that second part - then I would simply consider it _broken_. Are we talking about any "established" ORM - like Doctrine, Propel - or something self-written?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue then, in that case, and tell us which ORM product it is too. Because this should be fixable at source. Trying to unescape the data afterwards is a sticking plaster for a problem that should never occur in the first place, and in all probability is avoidable. Smells like a fairly classic [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: "Are we talking about any "established" ORM - like Doctrine, Propel - or something self-written" - Answering "yes" to that wasn't helpful.

Comment: Depending on your use case, it's not generally recommended to store a JSON string in a database anyways

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using stripslashes function of php.The stripslashes() function removes backslashes.

**Example**

```
<?php

$string = "{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Number five\",\"color\":\"red\"}";

$unescapedString = stripslashes($string);

echo $unescapedString; // Result -> {"id":6,"name":"Number five","color":"red"}

?>
```